# Deploying on Kubernetes with shared volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy this app [here](https://github.com/kaleidos-ventures/taiga-docker) on Kubernetes GKE.

```yaml
  
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/taiga: "true"
        io.kompose.service: taiga-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:1.19-alpine
          name: taiga-gateway
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
              
              name: taiga-gateway-claim0
            - mountPath: /taiga/static
              name: taiga-static-data
              
            - mountPath: /taiga/media
              name: taiga-media-data
              
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: taiga-gateway-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: taiga-gateway-claim0
        - name: taiga-static-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: taiga-static-data
        - name: taiga-media-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: taiga-media-data
status: {}
```

In kubernetes I am creating the volume this way

```yaml
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: taiga-static-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: taiga-media-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: taiga-db-data
..etc
```

So, I end up with the following error

> Normal   Scheduled               4m39s  default-scheduler
> Successfully assigned default/taiga-gateway-77976dc77-ppbvb to
> gke-taiga-cluster-default-pool-cccc58aa-jwfr   Warning
> FailedAttachVolume      4m39s  attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach
> error for volume "pvc-a28ae890-fe9d-4985-8183-ce54d7ed57d8" Volume is
> already used by pod(s) taiga-async-6c7d9dbd7b-vl79s   Warning
> FailedAttachVolume      4m39s  attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach
> error for volume "pvc-3cab3ec0-88d9-4c70-96c8-97d7b48e755c" Volume is
> already used by pod(s) taiga-async-6c7d9dbd7b-vl79s   Normal
> SuccessfulAttachVolume  4m32s  attachdetach-controller
> AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume
> "pvc-d2e39951-094f-447c-86ff-c36639786111"   Warning  FailedMount
> 2m36s  kubelet                  Unable to attach or mount volumes:
> unmounted volumes=[taiga-static-data taiga-media-data], unattached
> volumes=[taiga-static-data taiga-media-data kube-api-access-6lw4n
> taiga-gateway-claim0]: timed out waiting for the condition   Warning
> FailedMount             19s    kubelet                  Unable to
> attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[taiga-media-data
> taiga-static-data], unattached volumes=[taiga-media-data
> kube-api-access-6lw4n taiga-gateway-claim0 taiga-static-data]: timed
> out waiting for the condition

PVC status

```
testuser@cloudshell:~/kube-deploy (taiga-pursuit)$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                         STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
taiga-async-rabbitmq-data    Bound    pvc-3c8eb896-1bca-4047-915f-01e9a2ca5911   1Gi        RWO            standard       23m
taiga-db-data                Bound    pvc-ab03a878-1783-4f03-92bc-c9ef96a7d36d   5Gi        RWO            standard       23m
taiga-events-rabbitmq-data   Bound    pvc-0c4da3b5-bfb6-4cd9-b45d-e4e7b44a83e5   1Gi        RWO            standard       23m
taiga-gateway-claim0         Bound    pvc-d2e39951-094f-447c-86ff-c36639786111   5Gi        RWO            standard       24m
taiga-media-data             Bound    pvc-a28ae890-fe9d-4985-8183-ce54d7ed57d8   5Gi        RWO            standard       23m
taiga-static-data            Bound    pvc-3cab3ec0-88d9-4c70-96c8-97d7b48e755c   5Gi        RWO            standard       23m
```

Is the warning that these are being shared causing it to fail mounting or is it something else? I am not able to figure out

Comment: What is the `replicas` count of your deployment?

Comment: @gohm'c It is1. Node auto-provisioning is enabled.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @HemanthKumar https://medium.com/@abhishek.rai8992/deploying-a-docker-compose-app-in-kubernetes-c4536623bd28

Comment: Can you please post the same as answer @AbhishekRai

Comment: @HemanthKumar I don't think an article can be posted as an answer.